# Querying recent commits. Github GraphQL API v4

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I'm trying to query commits associated with my GitHub profile via GraphQL API (v4).

My goal is to display a list of 10 most recent commits with associated repositories (if public).

```
query getCommitActivity {
    user(login: "Login") {
     contributionsCollection{
      commitContributionsByRepository{
        contributions(first:5) {
           totalCount
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to completely ignore "commitsByRepo" and get the latest commits made by the given user?